# CakePHP Email Sending 0 bytes file attachment

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I need to attach a recent file to an email. The attachment is there, but it is 0 bytes. The path is correct

I have the following code, in part:

```
$file =  WWW_ROOT . $handle->file_dst_pathname; 
/* $file = /var/www/app/webroot/files/uploads/children/0000000220.pdf which is correct */

$attachment_name = 'Progress Note for ' . $parent['Child']['child_name'] . '-' . date('mdY') . '.' . $data['extension'];
$Email->attachments(array($attachment_name => $file));
```

I am using Cakephp 2.4.9

Any help is appreciated.

Greg

Comment: The possible cause is anything but obvious, what have you tried so far to debug the problem?

Comment: 1. Make sure that the file path is correct.
2. Tried different variation of the file path.
3. Tried on both, live and local servers.

Answer (score 0):

according to the docs 
`$Email->attachments(array(
    $attachment_name => array(
        'file' => '$file'
    )
));`

Comment: Here's the link to the docs where this is mentioned: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-attachments

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I made the adjustment, but still get 0 byte file.

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on the version of CakePHP you are using (2.x) and probably a version of PHP. I was struggling with the 0 bytes attachments as well. I had to dig in the vendor email file. Basically it turned out, that the _readFile() fn was messing things up with CakePHP File Reader.

So what worked for me was to specify the filename, specify the full path and attach the data of the file in base64. Then everything worked. All other options from documentation didnt work. I was running PHP 5.4.45 (old one).

```
    'filename' = array(
        'file' => '/full/path/to/the/file/on/disc.pdf',
        'data' => chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('/full/path/to/the/file/on/disc.pdf')))
    );
```